# Subquery question in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I'm not quite sure why the following query won't run in Access.
It asks me to give the value of s1.sku

```
SELECT s1.SkuApexId, s1.sku, s1.apex, s1.btw, s1.gebruikernr, q2.*
FROM tblSkuApex AS s1,
              (SELECT MAX(s2.begindatum)
              FROM tblskuapex  s2
              WHERE s1.sku = s2.sku) q2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you put it, you require a cross join to the q2 table, which is to be changing depending on the s1.sku value of each record of the s1 table, which is unacceptable.

I think you should place the q2 subquery as a column and not as a table. Since you retrieve a single value, it could be easily put like this:

```
SELECT s1.SkuApexId, s1.sku, s1.apex, s1.btw, s1.gebruikernr, 
         (SELECT MAX(s2.begindatum)
              FROM tblskuapex  s2
              WHERE s1.sku = s2.sku) as maxbegindatum
FROM tblSkuApex AS s1
```

or even better, why dont you get it as a normal aggregation, since you request the max from the same table:

```
SELECT 
    s1.SkuApexId, s1.sku, s1.apex, 
    s1.btw, s1.gebruikernr, MAX(begindatum)
FROM tblSkuApex AS s1
group by 
    s1.SkuApexId, s1.sku, s1.apex, 
    s1.btw, s1.gebruikernr
```

note: you could ommit the s1 alias everywhere